# Filter object with array is not able to get using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I tried filter object of arrays using filter but unable to get. i have used object as a filter field. and i am using filter with the given array.In each filter object i applied the filter field but unable to get filter result. below is my code

```js
var data = [{
    "schemaName": "test",
    "schemaType": "stype1",
    "functionalDomain": "domain1",
    "archiveFlag": "no"
  }, {
    "schemaName": "test2",
    "schemaType": "stype2",
    "functionalDomain": "domain2",
    "archiveFlag": null,
  }, {
    "schemaName": "test2",
    "schemaType": null,
    "functionalDomain": "domain2",
    "archiveFlag": null,
  }, {
    "schemaName": "test2",
    "schemaType": "stype2",
    "functionalDomain": null,
    "archiveFlag": "no"
  },
 {
    "schemaName": "test2",
    "schemaType": "stype1",
    "functionalDomain": "domain3",
    "archiveFlag": "no"
  },
 {
    "schemaName": "test1",
    "schemaType": "stype1",
    "functionalDomain": "domain3",
    "archiveFlag": "no"
  },
 {
    "schemaName": "test1",
    "schemaType": "stype1",
    "functionalDomain": "domain3",
    "archiveFlag": null
  }
];

var filterdata = {
  functionalDomain: ["domain1", "domain2", "domain3"],
  archiveFlag: "no",
  schemaType: ["stype1"]
};

var originalRes = data.filter((ele, indix) => {
  for (const prop in filterdata) {
    var fields = Array.isArray(filterdata[prop]) ? filterdata[prop] : [filterdata[prop]];
    if (ele[prop] === undefined || ele[prop] != filterdata[prop])
      return false;
    if (fields.includes(ele[prop]) === false) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
})

console.log(JSON.stringify(originalRes));
```

i need to filter based on multiple fields but unable to getting i am getting empty array. below is the expected output :

> [
>     {
>       "schemaName": "test",
>       "schemaType": "stype1",
>       "functionalDomain": "domain1",
>       "archiveFlag": "no"
>     },
>     {
>       "schemaName": "test2",
>       "schemaType": "stype1",
>       "functionalDomain": "domain3",
>       "archiveFlag": "no"
>     },
>     {
>       "schemaName": "test1",
>       "schemaType": "stype1",
>       "functionalDomain": "domain3",
>       "archiveFlag": "no"
>     }
>   ]

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: i have added expected output in question, please help me to get this one

Comment: what do you want to filter based on ?

Comment: based on    (schemaType,functionalDomain,archiveFlag)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this works. You could take a more cleaner approach and use null instead of no for archiveFlag.

```
const allowedDomains = ["domain1","domain2","domain3"];
const allowedSchemas = ["stype1"];

data.filter(el => (allowedDomains.includes(el.functionalDomain)) &&
 (allowedSchemas.includes(el.schemaType)) &&
(!el.archiveFlag))
```

Comment: For example allowedDomains is empty array how i will pass dynamically inside filter

Comment: Please be clear. What should the schemaType be ? What should the functionalDomain be ? What should the archiveFlag be ?

Comment: schemaType  is array, functionalDomain is array, archiveFlag is string("yes/no")

Comment: ok. for your scenario, what should the allowed Schema be ? What should the allowed domain be ?